# Bar chart formatting

Tags: r

I can't seem to wrap my head around the way R does barplots. I am trying to plot data and in my mind this should be very straight forward. Here is what my Excel file looks like before exporting to .csv with `Stats` and `Value` being headers:

```
Stats    Value
error1   5034
error2   0
error3   99
error4   12
```

I have 60 different errors that I am plotting and here is the code I am using.

```
x <- read.csv("C:/Users/test/Desktop/test2.csv", header = T)
stats.freq <- table(x$value)
barplot(stats.freq)
```

This plots them so that it counts the frequency of value instead of just plotting the value. I understand barplots are categorical so maybe this kind of plot is not what I am looking for. I would like the plot to have each error listed horizontally in the x axis under the appropriate bar and the y axis would simply be the value of error. For instance a bar would be named `error3` and the y axis would show 99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have your data in the proper format, so there is no need to tabulate it with `table`.  Here are a few options

```
## Base R
barplot(x$Value, names.arg=x$Stats)

## Alternatives
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(x=Stats, y=Value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

library(lattice)
barchart(Value ~ Stats, data=x, ylim=c(0, 5100))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. What would be an example of data that would need to be converted.

Comment: @Schylar well, say you had observations about the time these errors occurred (so many observations of each error type).  Then, if you wanted to look at a chart like this, you would tabulate the data (by error type), thus getting the number of occurrences for each error type - then do the above.