# How to barplot in R using the first column as data labels

Tags: r, label, bar-chart

Below is my data, with headers.

Using R, I would like to `barplot()` this data using the value in the `S` column as the label.

```
S  Value
10  0.00
20  0.00
30  0.00
40  0.01
50  0.71
60  4.97
70 13.22
80 22.95
90 32.93
100 42.93
```

I'm scouring the help files, but I can't seem to find an example of this seemingly simple task.

Comment: is the `names.arg = S` what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866271/bar-chart-formatting

Comment: yup, thx. If you want to write up a quick example I'll mark it the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will quickly resolve your problem, but then you'll have to add details to set the graph details layout:
Your example:

```
S <- c(10, 20,30,40,50,6,70,80,90,100)
Value <- c(0.00,0.00,0.00,0.01,0.71,4.97,13.22,22.95,32.93,42.93)
df <- do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, S=S, Value=Value))
df

S Value
1   10  0.00
2   20  0.00
3   30  0.00
4   40  0.01
5   50  0.71
6    6  4.97
7   70 13.22
8   80 22.95
9   90 32.93
10 100 42.93

barplot(df$Value, names.arg = df$S)
```

[image]